# Access token invalid after configuring Microsoft Azure Active Directory for Snowflake External OAuth

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to Configure Microsoft Azure AD for External OAuth as per the Snowflake tutorial: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html

The configuration steps went ahead without a hitch and I was able to use the final step: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure.html#testing-procedure to obtain the access token from AAD.

However, when I tried to use the access token with Snowflake using a JDBC driver, I obtained the error: `"net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Invalid OAuth access token.`

The Snowflake integration created is of the form:

```
create security integration ext_oauth_azure_ad
    type = external_oauth
    enabled = true
    external_oauth_type = azure
    external_oauth_issuer = '<issuer-url>'
    external_oauth_jws_keys_url = '<keys-url>/discovery/v2.0/keys'
    external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://<app-id-uri>')
    external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim = 'upn'
    external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute = 'login_name'
    external_oauth_any_role_mode = 'ENABLE';
```

I tried playing around with this config by changing the `external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim` to `email` since that was the attribute in the decoded JWT access token that matched the `login_name` but to no avail.

The scope provided in AD is the `session:role-any` which should be valid for any scope.

Not sure how to proceed post this.

Edit:

The command used to obtain access token is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"   --data-urlencode "client_id=<ad-client-id>"   --data-urlencode "client_secret=<ad-client-secret>"   --data-urlencode "username=<ad-user-email>"   --data-urlencode "password=<my-password>"   --data-urlencode "grant_type=password"   --data-urlencode "scope=<scope-as-in-ad>" 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

Update:

Tried using the command:
`select system$verify_external_oauth_token('<access_token>');`
to validate if the token was valid in Snowflake and obtained the result:

`Token Validation finished.{"Validation Result":"Failed","Failure Reason":"EXTERNAL_OAUTH_INVALID_SIGNATURE"}`

This is strange because I have added the correct issuer based on the configuration step(entityId from the Federation metadata document
)

Comment: Please share the code of getting the access token.

Comment: @AllenWu Have added the command. I've been using a curl command to get the token. But obtaining a token using the interactive approach(using the authorise endpoint) also works but when trying to connect, it gives the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<client-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token` as the authority? The `<client-id>` is incorrect. You should use tenant id.

Comment: @AllenWu Oops, I had taken it directly from the metadata. Yes I am using the tenant id only there. Updated the command in the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you check the actual value  of `SNOWFLAKE_APPLICATION_ID_URI` and `scope=<scope-as-in-ad>`? They should be matched. For example, `SNOWFLAKE_APPLICATION_ID_URI` is `https://your.company.com/4d2a8c2b-a5f4-4b86-93ca-294185f45f2e`, then scope should be `https://your.company.com/4d2a8c2b-a5f4-4b86-93ca-294185f45f2e/.default`.

Comment: @AllenWu Sure, I copied most of these directly from Azure but will double check and let you know here. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @AllenWu Have confirmed that the application-id-url and the scope-as-in-id url are the same. Have updated the question with some more info after trying to manually verify the token in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Use your Azure application specific oauth configuration URLs in your snowflake config (CREATE SECURITY INTEGRATION) to point to the correct keys:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?appid={appid}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant%7D/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?appid=%7Bappid%7D)

In the response to this url you will find jwks_uri specific to this Application (client) ID that is used for the EXTERNAL_OAUTH_JWS_KEYS_URL snowflake parameter.  When you change this you may notice your token is shorter.

I also found that I needed to adjust EXTERNAL_OAUTH_AUDIENCE_LIST to match the aud field in the token issued, but there is a more helpful error for that when you run into it.  Use https://jwt.ms to see this field in your token.

I also found that the token did not contain the "upn" field so I switched it to EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TOKEN_USER_MAPPING_CLAIM = 'preferred_username' which was present in the token.

The https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-azure guide as of this writing is overly complicated and wrong and needs to be updated for oauth2 v2 and Azure.  The steps for user token and device token need to be in separate sections, not intermingled.

Best luck!